# What is the output of GetSPOFolderMetadata

Tags: http, web, sharepoint

Please I need your help on this, what is the output of GetSPOFolderMetadata, I am working with files in a sharepoint folder I know that GetSPOFolderMetadata will return a json file but I want to know what are the column that we have is it similaire to this:

{
"name": "ghg.xlsx",
"type": "File",
"relativeUrl": "/sites/site1/folderK/ghg.xlsx",
"size": 67890,
"createdDateTime": "2022-03-20T11:15:00Z",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-04-03T16:30:00Z"
}

so to get the url I should use the relativeUrl and to get the name of the file I should use name column